# XHR Wrapper POST method not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, post, xmlhttprequest

Im trying to do a Wrapper XMLHTTPRequest in javascript. I did the GET method and it works fine, but when it comes to the POST method it gives me an error:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/text2.txt 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> XHR failed loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:8080/text2.txt".

Im running a local http-server with node

I have one week stuck in this problem and i would really like to know how i can get this to work

This is my js code:

```
var wrapper = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = 'Name=Cesar';

function getText2() {
    wrapper.open('POST', 'text2.txt');
    wrapper.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    wrapper.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('Name').value = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    wrapper.send(params);
}
```

And this is my html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="XHR.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>WRAPPER</h2>

        Name: <input type="text" id="Name"/>

        <button type="button" onclick="getText2()">
        Post Test</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your server doesn't seem to accept the POST method.

Comment: how can i change that?

Comment: You'd have to check your server configuration.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/438183/how-to-enable-all-http-methods-in-an-apache-http-server

Comment: i've been looking how can i change the configuration of node local httpserver but havent find anything, it would be really nice if you can guide me through this, im new to this